# Convert Base64 String to BitMap and Draw rectangle with pixel coordinates

Tags: c#, .net, bitmap, base64

I have `Base64` string with headers, I am trying to convert it to `BitMap` and Draw polygon with 4 pixel coordinates in **C#.NET 4.7 (Class Library)**

Here is my method:

```
public Image MarkPixelCoordinates(Image image, string pixelCoordinates)
{
    try
    {
        image.OriginalBase64 = image.Base64;
        string converted = image.Base64.Split(',').ToList<string>()[1];
            var bitMapImage = Base64StringToBitmap(converted);
            var coordinates = pixelCoordinates.Split(',').ToList();
            foreach (var coordinate in coordinates)
            {
                var xys = coordinate.Split(':').Select(int.Parse).ToList();
                bitMapImage.SetPixel(xys[0], xys[1], Color.DarkSalmon);
            }

            using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                bitMapImage.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
                byte[] byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                image.Base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage); 
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Commentary.Print(
            $"Failed to mark pixel coordinates");
        Commentary.Print(e.Message);
        return image;
    }

    return image;
}
```

Here is the method to convert `Base64` to `BitMap`:

```
private static Bitmap Base64StringToBitmap(string base64String)
{
    byte[] byteBuffer = Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);
    using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream(byteBuffer))
    {
        var bmpReturn = (Bitmap) System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Close();
        return bmpReturn;
    }
}
```

Here is my `Base64` string and Pixel coordinates:

[Base64String Download Link](https://ufile.io/264n3)

Input for pixel coordinates are like this

```
"1023:762,1046:842,1326:849,1261:738"
```

Error I am getting:

> Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: That means your base64 string is invalid, just as message says. Probably lacks correct padding. Where did you get that base64 string from?

Comment: An Image object created from a stream [will need the stream to remain open for the entire life cycle of the image object.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z7ha67kw(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) You _cannot_ use a `using` block for this. Ignoring this rule will give errors when you try to manipulate the image later. Also, explicitly closing the stream is pointless if you use a `using` block; it'll happen automatically, even if you `return` or have an exception inside the block.

Comment: @Evk base64 is right. I get it from API, I can render that on a webpage in image tag and it works. There is something else I am missing in conveying that base64 to bitmap

Comment: @Nyerguds my problem is even before getting into using blockit fails at this line Convert.FromBase64String(base64String);

Comment: I downloaded your base64.txt file and used it in html - browser cannot display it until I add couple of bytes at the end. Because as is - it's invalid base64 string, believe it or not. Maybe some browser (like Internet Explorer) allows even invalid base64 images (by, for example, removing last byte, which is invalid), but most browsers do not.

Comment: @Evk how did you add extra bytes to base64? can you share the pseudo code?

Comment: I actually removed, not added. In case of this specific string from your question - just remove last character (`base64String = base64String.Remove(base64String.Length - 1, 1);`) and it will convert ot bitmap just fine. I hope it's obvious that it's not general solution - general solution is just fix api to produce valid base64 strings.

Comment: This is one Base64 case, how can I dynamically check if a Base64 is not valid then fix it and convert it to BitMap?

Comment: @Evk by removing the last char, its removing image

Comment: I don't remember details of this question already, but as I remember I removed last char and then it displayed image in browser, though image was not complete (only top half, or top quater even). I also removed last char and loaded it in `Bitmap` and it loaded fine (so, didn't throw exception, width and height were valid and so on).  I'm not sure how I can help you any futher. I stand on my claim that your base64 is invalid (or incomplete, or both invalid and incomplete).